# Spyne SOAP server WSDL file cannot show https

Tags: python, soap, https, spyne

My Spyne server WSDL shows 
`<soap:address location="http://some-domain.com>`

I want it to show `https` instead of `http`.

Basically, `<soap:address location="https://some-domain.com>`

Notice the difference lies in `http` and `https`.

How do I tell my Spyne server to address this?

Have gone through the docs multiple times but could not figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue from terminating SSL at a load balancer.

Assuming you are using the WsgiApplication, you can specify the URL you want via the `build_interface_document` method. Something like this from the sample soap app.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # You can use any Wsgi server. Here, we chose
    # Python's built-in wsgi server but you're not
    # supposed to use it in production.

    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
    wsgi_app.doc.wsdl11.build_interface_document('https://some-hardcoded-url.blah.io')
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 80, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

It's documented here, though I missed it on the first read thru: http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/server.html#module-spyne.server.wsgi

Answer (score -1):

WSDL url is constructed from the first request.

Upon starting the server, request the wsdl from the secure domain and it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand that. What changes do I need to make on the Spyne server?

Comment: Facing the same issue on requested the WSDL from https